# Game Center not asking my TestFlight users to log in?

Tags: testflight

In my app, I use the following code in the view controller in my sprite kit project to authenticate a player using GameKit:

```
-(void)autheticateLocalPlayer{
    GKLocalPlayer *localPlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];

    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error){
        if (error != nil){
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        if (viewController != nil){
            [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }else{
            if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated){
                _gameCenterEnabled = YES;
                [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer]loadDefaultLeaderboardIdentifierWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString *leaderboardIdentifier, NSError *error) {
                    if (error != nil){
                        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    }
                    else{
                        _leaderboardIdentifier = leaderboardIdentifier;
                    }
                }];

            }
            else{
                _gameCenterEnabled = NO;
                NSLog(@"game center not available");
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It works fine on my phone, but after building an Ad-Hoc build with a provisioning profile including a friend's phone to see how it would work, they were not asked to log in when they opened the app, whereas my phone was (and all simulator phones were).

On top of that, attempting to open the leaderboards would simply show a message "game center is not available, user is not logged in" or something like that.

I went to this friend's phone's Game Center settings, and verified that sandbox mode was ON. After that, I manually logged in to a Sandbox tester account I made in iTunes connect, and once I opened my app again, (on their phone), it displayed the "welcome back" message. However, the leaderboards showed "no scores", when I believe that my score should be on there.

My questions are:

**1. Why were they not asked to log in? Is it a problem with my code, or is that how it's supposed to work when beta testing with sandbox mode on?**

**2. Why doesn't it show the other scores? My leaderboard is in iTunes connect, and the leaderboard name is properly displayed in the app, but no score are visible.**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it takes about 10 hours before the other user's scores will be updated. Today, all of my test users' scores are on game center. Would be nice if this was made more obvious, so developers didn't think Game Center wasn't working.

Comment: I am having same problem. none of my user are being asked. but I am in beta testing last 20 days. Do they need to check sandbox tester switch. I am so confused. all of users that I have been testing as sandbox are in the list. Can you shed some light on this. Thanks.